# Trying to use JSR330ScopeMetadataResolver with Spring boot without success

Tags: spring-boot, jsr330

I am trying to retrofit Spring DI into an existing application using Spring Boot.  I want to use JSR-330 annotations instead of Spring's.  I would like to make prototype scope the default so I don't have to use non-JSR-330 scope @Scope("prototype") everywhere.  I first tried to install the JSR330ScopeMetadataResolver using:

```
  SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(OurApplication.class);
  ConfigurableApplicationContext context = application.createContext();
  context..setScopeMetadataResolver(new Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver());
  application.run(args);
```

I still get a singleton when injecting a class with no annotation.  I then tried using an ApplicationContextInitializer to do the same thing.  Either way, I get a singleton injected.  In the debugger, I verified with the initializer that Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver is getting set in the ApplicationContext. In the Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver instance, I see a map is getting populated in the default constructor with key /value as singleton.  I obviously are missing something.  Does anyone know what that is?

Comment: I did some more debugging. JSR330ScopeMetadataResolver is installed, and the Map contains "javax.inject.Singleton" -> "Singleton" as it should.  The problem is, the breakpoint I put inside resolveScopeMetadata() never pops.  The method is never getting called to override Spring's default behavior.  Does anyone know why not?

Answer (score 1):

We finally were able to figure this out.  The solution was:

```
  private static final String CONTEXT_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = 
      "my.company.package.*";


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(
          MainApplication.class);
      application.addInitializers(new Jsr330Initializer());
      application.run(args);
  }


  public static class Jsr330Initializer implements 
      ApplicationContextInitializer<AnnotationConfigApplicationContext> 
  {

      @Override
      public void initialize(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context) {
          context.setScopeMetadataResolver(new Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver());
          context.scan(CONTEXT_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
      }
}
```

The key is to perform context.scan() in the initializer.  Packages to scan must end in ".*", or the main application gets added twice and Spring fails to start.